# How to replace comma with a dot in the number (or any replacement)

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, jscript

I could not found a solution yet, for replacing , with a dot.

```
var tt="88,9827";
tt.replace(/,/g, '.')
alert(tt)

//88,9827
```

i'm trying to replace a comma a dot

thanks in advance

Comment: I know it's a super old question, but for those who have complex CSV-like strings my comment might be interesting. If you want to replace commas with dots in a string like this one: "0,001; x,y,z; 0,a;b,1; 2,45;" using the accepted answers won't work. You can then try something like that: ````var res = tt.replace(/([0-9]{1,})(,)([0-9]{1,})/g,"$1.$3");```` This will match the commas only if they are surrounded by at least one number from each side.

Answer (score 123, accepted):

As `replace()` creates/returns a new string rather than modifying the original (`tt`), you need to set the variable (`tt`) equal to the new string returned from the `replace` function.

```
tt = tt.replace(/,/g, '.')
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VKp65/)

Comment: If you use this for any string, you might run into problems. E.g. inputs like `1, 2, 3` turn into `1. 2. 3`. To make sure you have a number, see solution at https://stackoverflow.com/q/52329376/1066234

Answer (score 21):

You can also do it like this:

```
var tt="88,9827";
tt=tt.replace(",", ".");
alert(tt);
```

[working fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/62dbm/)

Answer (score 5):

After replacing the character, you need to be asign to the variable.

```
var tt = "88,9827";
tt = tt.replace(/,/g, '.')
alert(tt)
```

In the alert box it will shows **88.9827**

Answer (score 3):

From the function's definition (http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp):

> The replace() method searches a string for a specified value, or a
>   regular expression, and returns a new string where the specified
>   values are replaced.
>
> **This method does not change the original string.**

Hence, the line: `tt.replace(/,/g, '.')` does not change the value of `tt`; it just *returns* the new value.

You need to replace this line with: `tt = tt.replace(/,/g, '.')`

Answer (score 1):

Per [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace), `replace` returns the new string - it does not modify the string you pass it.

```
var tt="88,9827";
tt = tt.replace(/,/g, '.');
^^^^
alert(tt);
```

Comment: @Leo don't actually type the carets.

Answer (score 1):

This will need new var `ttfixed`

Then this under the `tt` value slot and replace all pointers down below that are `tt` to `ttfixed`

```
ttfixed = (tt.replace(",", "."));
```

Comment: Please take time to improve formatting of your answer.

Comment: The extra parentheses is unnecessary, and as the OP was hoping to change the original var there is no need to create a new one. Also if you are going to create a new one, you should add `var` in front to avoid creating a global var.

Comment: This is a very simple yet effective solution.