# Capitalization Regex to allow for Hyphenated Names

Tags: regex, jscript

I have this regex (dug up form somewhere)

```
return str.replace(/\w\S*/g, function(txt){return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase();});
```

that Capitalizes the First Characters of a Prsons name.

It does not handle a Hyphanated Name like

```
melinda-ann smith
```

and returns

```
Melinda-ann Smith
```

when it should be

```
Melinda-Ann Smith
```

Regex is a very weak point with me, ... What do I need to change to Capitalize the character after the hyphen.

Answer (score 3):

Found the Solution

`str.replace(/\b[\w']+\b/g, function(txt){return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase();});`

works just fine .

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend for this purpose not to use such procedural language and use more functional and more extendabale.

This function makes capitalization of first letter in regular and hyphened names(including with 'minus' sign or 'hyphen' -> [- –])

```
const startCase = (string) => 
  _.compact(string.split(' '))
          .map((word) => word.split(/[-–]/).map(_.capitalize).join('-'))
          .join(' ') // "melinda-ann smith" -> "Melinda-Ann Smith"
```

Comment: Would be nice if you can explain what your code is doing and how it address the OP question.

Comment: this code makes capitalization of first letter in regular and hyphened names(including with 'minus' sign or 'hyphen' -> [- –]). I believe it is more functionally correct - then the making it as in the question with str.replace(....)

Comment: You should  edit your answer instead putting the detail in comment. [Example of a good answer referring the doc](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17320218/628006)

Comment: is it better now?

Comment: yes sure it is always best to explain and document as much as possible your answers with code even if sometimes it can be easy or obvious for experienced developers, probably beginners can still like to have the "why".

Answer (score 0):

Inorder to make it capitalize, first non-uppercase letter like this:

```
'~\b([a-z])~'
```

it make `melinda-ann smith` to `Melinda-Ann Smith`