# Replace comma with period in string only if it is a decimal number

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to scan a string and check if there are decimals (in numbers). If so, replace them with commas. Example:

```
var string = "This is the number 9,5 but problem is if we have e.g. 10, 11."
```

Using the simplest solution:

```
string = string.replace(/,/g, '.')
```

will replace all commas in the string.

So I am in need of a regex that does check if the previous character and the following character of `,` are digits `\d`, only then replace the `,` with a `.`.

What I achieved is to get those numbers by regex:

```
\d(\,)\d
```

But I do not know how to use (non) capturing groups to only extract the comma for the javascript replace. Or any other way of how to do it.

Comment: Since JS doesn't support a zero-length lookbehind, you are probably better off capturing the digits in a group and then put them back in.

Comment: I always wonder what douchebag votes down questions like that. There should be a mandatory "state a reason for your down vote" field in SO.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Capture a digit, match a comma, lookahead for another digit, and replace with the  captured group plus a period:

```js
var string = "This is the number 9,5 but problems is if we have e.g. 10, 11."
console.log(
  string.replace(/(\d),(?=\d)/g, '$1.')
);
```

Comment: Damn, I wrote a comment to preciselt that effect and you posted an entire answer at the same time... :P

Comment: @kai-noack your ownn regex would have worked as well had you used capturing groups. E.g. `string.replace(/(\d),(\d)/g, '$1.$2');`

Comment: **/(\d),(\d)/g** is actually a bit quick (124 steps) than **/(\d),(?=\d)/g** (128 steps)