# Currency: Dot to Comma?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Using JavaScript, what is correct approach to replace the dot to comma (For EU currency), for example:

`2000.65` would be `2000,65` instead of `2,000.65`

`39.20` would be `39,20`

I am not sure if `cost.replace('.', ',')` is the right way. Is there a better option?

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17320162/how-to-replace-comma-with-a-dot-in-the-number-or-any-replacement

You have a duplicated question.

Comment: Sounds like a localization problem. There might be js native solutions.

Comment: http://openexchangerates.github.io/accounting.js/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I format numbers as dollars currency string in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149055/how-can-i-format-numbers-as-dollars-currency-string-in-javascript)

Answer (score 8):

You can use [Intl.NumberFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat)

```js
const n = 2000.65;

console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat('de-DE', {
  style: 'currency',
  currency: 'EUR'
}).format(n));
```

There are [some more options available](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat#Parameter), like showing the thousand seperator or not, or displaying the `€` sign or not. Below will only display the number in european notation, without thousands separator.

```js
const n = 2000.65;

console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat('de-DE', {
   useGrouping: false,
}).format(n));
```

Comment: de-DE? not FR?.

Comment: Whatever you want. I'm german - but you can use fr-FR too. @user88432

Comment: I am getting `2000.65` instead of `2000,65` (Testing on NodeJs)

Comment: Please be more precise. You're getting that for what code? @user88432

Comment: It work on Chrome but not on Node.js. The second option you given me without € sign

Answer (score 4):

Try using `toLocaleString()`

Example:

```
    var d = 1000000.54;
    var n = d.toLocaleString(); // output would be 1,000,000.54
    console.log(n);
```

Comment: what if I have a dynamic config to use comma or dot format? is it possible to change the output for `toLocaleString`?